# Send data from form to one page and go to another

Tags: php, html

I have a form where the user will input a bunch of data. It is set up like this:

```
<form action="add.php" method="post">
```

This makes it so that when I click my submit button it will go to the add.php page. add.php however is a blank page because it only runs some SQL queries and does nothing else.

I want it so that when I click submit, the information is sent one place and the screen goes to another. My button is set up like this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Just to make sure I am explaining the issue correctly, when I click submit I want the data from the form to go to add.php, and the browser to display a different page rather than displaying the add.php page, which is what it is doing right now.

Comment: You can either make a redirect with php on the `add.php` page or send the data via ajax and redirect after via javascript. I would probably go with the latter

Comment: In PHP - `header('Location: SomeOtherPlace.php'):` [The manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: `<form action="" method="post">` run you form and save the form data in a session, then redirect to another form. lastly, save the session values in the db at your last form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is easy, send data to `add.php`, in the end of your process. redirect to another page, let's say  `page.php`

on your  `add.php`

```
 <?php 

 /// do you mysql stuffs here
header('Location: page.php');
?>
```

Comment: But how do you do about doing the redirection?

Comment: And where would that redirect go? In the add.php file? If you put the redirect at the top of that file will the queries below it still execute?

Comment: @D.Hoffman at the end of file, after you put data into the mysql.

Comment: It works for me! Thanks! Any reason why this is getting down voted?

Comment: @D.Hoffman, I don't know. some guys that think they are very expert think this question is very easy but they forgotten once they very newbie. btw, I'm happy could help you. don't forget to mark answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Here is two solutions :

**Asynchronous solution**

Use Javascript and ajax to send the data to `add.php` asynchronously and redirect the user to the page you want.

> This solution might be not a good one, because the process result of `add.php` is ignored (if you redirect the user before getting the result)

**Synchronous solution**

Redirect the user to `add.php`, then, redirect the user to the page you want at the end of the process.

Answer (score 0):

After your SQL Queries are done on `add.php` you can use the header function and pass your data via `get`-method:

```
header("Location: nextSite.php?key=value"); //Replace key and value with whatever you want
```

Answer (score 0):

1. we can use a session or cookie in PHP.
   Session:

   //On page 1
   `$_SESSION['name'] = $formvariable;` // You can use document.getElementById('form input 
   name')

   //On page 2
   $var_value = $_SESSION['name'];
2. Using include method
   //On page 1
   This page has a form without submit button
   //On page 2
   This page has a submit button
   so we include page 1 something like this.

EX:

```
vars.php
<?php

$color = 'green';
$fruit = 'apple';

?>

test.php
<?php

echo "A $color $fruit"; // A

include 'vars.php';

echo "A $color $fruit"; // A green apple

?>
```

I hope this will help you to solve your issue- thanks!